# How to get base uri of site on application start?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have asp.net mvc application. I was using the following code to get base URI inside controller.

```
var baseApplicationUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}", HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority);
```

this was working fine.

Is there a way to construct baseuri in  Application_Start()?
In application start method `HttpContext.Current.Request` will throw exception

**Update 1**
I have a `UISettings` class which holds some links. The base URI of these links would be different based on how the application is hosted. For example it could be `http://www.example.com/home/index` or `https://www.example.com/home/index` or `http://www.example.com/subdomain/home/index`. so `home/index` has different base uri depends on how its hosted.

I understand that the request is not available on application start. But i wanted to load the UISettings on application start so i can register with DI framework as singleton instance.

```
public class UISettings
{
   public string Link1 {get;set;}
   public string Link2 {get;set;}

   public static UiSettings Load()
   {
     // need to get baseURI here???

      var settings = new UISettings();
      settings.Link1 = baseURI + "/home/index";          
      return settings;
   }
}
```

and then register with DI framework as singleton on application start so i can inject it in any class latter

```
  container.RegisterInstance<UISettings>(UiSettings.Load());
```

Comment: See http://mvolo.com/iis7-integrated-mode-request-is-not-available-in-this-context-exception-in-applicationstart/ .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here. At Application_Start() stage Request is not constructed yet, so I think the earliest time you can get URI from Current Request is in Aplication_BeginRequest(), before then it is your starting page that can be assigned in and used from WebConfig file.